# mysql multi count() in one query

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to count several joined tables but without any luck, what I get is the same numbers for every column `(tUsers,tLists,tItems)`. My query is:

```
select COUNT(users.*) as tUsers,
       COUNT(lists.*) as tLists,
       COUNT(items.*) as tItems,
       companyName
    from users as c
    join lists as l
    on c.userID = l.userID
    join items as i
    on c.userID = i.userID
    group by companyID
```

The result I want to get is

```
---------------------------------------------
 #  | CompanyName | tUsers | tlists | tItems 
 1  | RealCoName  |    5   |   2    |   15
---------------------------------------------
```

what modifications do i have to do to my query to get those results?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT u.userID, companyName, 
       Count(DISTINCT l.listid) as tLists, Count(DISTINCT i.items) as tItems
 FROM users u
   LEFT JOIN lists l ON u.userID=l.userID
   LEFT JOIN items i ON u.userID=i.userID 
GROUP BY u.companyID
```

Comment: Hi Shakti Singh, that query gives me the results I wanted. I just added "Count(DISTINCT u.userID) as tUsers". I didn't knew about the existence of DISTINCT, thank you for that.

Comment: This worked for something I'm working on as well. My only question is why is the distinct needed for each `count` column?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using sub query

```
select (select count(*) from users where userID=YourUserID) tUsers,
       (select count(*) from lists where userID=YourUserID) as tLists,
       (select count(*) from items where userID=YourUserID) as tItems,
       companyName
    from company group by companyID
```

Comment: hi shankhan, i won't insert "YourUserID" using an application, "YourUserID" is coming from the JOINs. Can you please modify your query so it does that?

Comment: hmm in that case you will have to write join in each sub query and it will be little costly